# How to load a session from local cache (i.e store a session in Map) and it will be work similar when load session from Database?

Tags: jbpm

When create a session that time session data will be save into database.So, my requirement is session data will be save into local cache(i.e persist a session into Map). When reload a session it's work fine but it isn't similar to work when loading the session from database.

Let's take example(Async workflow) like :

1. jBPM Workflow contains 3 work items.Create session then persist data into   DB automatically.
2. Once 1 st work item completed then session dispose. Again session reload from database and 2 nd 3rd work items are also work same like that only.

I am doing same scenario in locally(Persist a session in Map) without using Database then  reload session from local cache(i.e Map) it's work fine but when 1st work item is completed the dispose a session, I got an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed.

but when don't want dispose a session it's work fine but it's mandatory to close a session right.

Please give a solution  ?